# Rails split query view into two different div

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I have the following rails app, where I need to pass the results into view as 2 different row `<div>` each row comes with 4 result, total 8 for 2 row.

```
    </section>
        <div class="container landing-content">
            <!-- Projects Row -->
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 text-center content-title">
                    <h3>Now trending in Kuala Lumpur</h3>
                </div>
               <% @products.each do |product| %>
                <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
                    <p class="price">RM <%= product.price_cents/100 %></p>
                    <a href="<%= product_path product %>"><img src="<%= product.user.store_setting.store_image.store_img.small%>" class="img-circle user-thumb" width="52"/></a>
                    <a href="<%= product_path product %>">
                    <img class="img-responsive" src="<%= product.product_attachments.first.attachment.small.url%>" width="262" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <h4>
                        <a href="<%= product_path product %>"><%= product.name %></a>
                    </h4>
                    <a href="<%= product_path product %>">
                        <p><%= product.city%>, <%= product.country%></p>
                    </a>
                </div>
                <% end %>
    </div>

       <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
</div>
</div>

    </div>
    </section>
```

The question is, how can I split my 8 result into 2 different div? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think I should go from your view to clarify my idea:

```
</section>
  <div class="container landing-content">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center content-title">
         <h3>Now trending in Kuala Lumpur</h3>
      </div>
    </div>
    <% @products.each_slice(4).each do |slice| %>
      <div class="row">
        <% slice.each do |product| %>
          <div class="col-md-3 portfolio-item">
            <p class="price">RM <%= product.price_cents/100 %></p>
            <a href="<%= product_path product %>"><img src="<%= product.user.store_setting.store_image.store_img.small%>" class="img-circle user-thumb" width="52"/></a>
            <a href="<%= product_path product %>"><img class="img-responsive" src="<%= product.product_attachments.first.attachment.small.url%>" width="262" alt=""></a>
            <h4>
              <a href="<%= product_path product %>"><%= product.name %></a>
            </h4>
            <a href="<%= product_path product %>">
              <p><%= product.city%>, <%= product.country%></p>
            </a>
          </div>
        <% end %>
      </div>
   <% end %>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Should I place the @products.each_slice(4).each do |slice| before the row div?

Comment: Yes, you should. Also, place your row before the slice.each should do the trick.